# NodeJS SSL error when using request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

Somebody can explain to me what is the source of this error?

> { Error: write EPROTO 139632733071168:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1407:SSL alert number 40 at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:832:14) errno: 'EPROTO', code: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write' }

Comment: Looks like you're trying connect to something that may not be supporting SSL

Comment: That error means that the client that cannot connect to your Secure Server, you can catch the error by doing something like `netSv.on('clientError', function(e){ console.log(e); // now your server won't crash })`. Update your question with what you try to achieve, what 'request' are you using http.request or request npm package, and some code about the server and the client.